# A Google extension without Omnibar Icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

This is probably a simple question, but I'm trying to create a Google extension without an icon, one that just runs in the background without a popup or anything. What would I put into the manifest to get this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove this from the `manifest.json`:

```
...
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
...
```

Now the app will not appear in the top bar.